# Return class instance using generic inside companion object for method specified in trait

Tags: scala, generics

In **Scala** I want to return a instance of a class for a method defined in a trait which uses generics, the code example I have is this:

**File 1**

```
package packOne

import packTwo.A

trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T <: A]] {
    def otherFunct(): String
    def funct[T <: A](): T
}
```

**File 2**

```
package packTwo

import packOne.MyTrait

abstract class A(someParameter: String) {}

class B(someParameter: String) extends A(someParameter) {}

object B extends MyTrait[B] { // <--- the B inside MyTrait here is the class not the object, or at least that is what I want
    def otherFunct(): String = "Hello"
    def funct[B](): C = new B("hi") // <--- I think here is the key
}
```

basically what I want is an interface that have method to return a concrete implementation of class `A`, in an implementing object *(which happen to be a companion object for a class extending `A`)*.

*Why do I want that to be on an object?*, is because I want to call that method without the need of an instance (like an static method in java), so that I can call `B.funct()` and have an instance of B class kind of like a *factory method*, for other classes extending `A` for example a call to `X.funct` will return an instance of class `X`.

I have tried to remove the generic type from the function definition except on the return type of the function and just leave it in the trait definition (like `def funct(): T`) but that does not work either.

I am quite new to **Scala** so if you could explain it for dummies and avoid complex *scala unique* concepts I would appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply:

```
trait A
class B(someParameter: String) extends A

trait MyTrait[T <: A] {
    def otherFunct: String //Parentheses on parameterless methods with no side effects and no serious computation are generally unidiomatic in Scala 
    def funct: T //Note, no generic parameter on this method
}

object B extends MyTrait[B] {
    def otherFunct = "Hello"
    def funct = new B("hi")
}
```

And then:

```
B.funct //returns a new `B`
```

The `apply` method is often used in this factory style (e.g. `Seq.apply()` which is equivalent to `Seq()`)

Comment: Thanks apparently I got it to work, with just some small changes `trait A` as `abstract class A(someParameter: String)`, and either remove the colon from `otherFunct` in `object B` or add `String`, please let me know if that is what you where intending to say or I just miss read

Comment: The colon was just a typo (fixed).  The `abstract class`/`trait` change was just because it didn't seem so relevant to the problem so I just changed it to save a few characters.